# Unless AND (&&) in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use

```
unless @a && @b
   -- data here
end
```

I don't want to use

```
 if !(@a && @b)
```

If you have any suggestion, as unless and is not working.

Comment: What does not working mean? works fine for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You solved the question yourself really. Use brackets :)

```
unless (@a && @b)
    #...
end
```